# What does finding a "free local ring" have to do with finding the spectrum of a ring?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, intuition, topos-theory, local-rings

In Tierney's 1976 paper *On the Spectrum of a Ringed Topos* (which you can find [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780123390509500201)) at the top of section 2 we read

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring in [a topos] $\mathbf{E}$. We look at the problem of finding the spectrum of $A$ as the problem of finding a free local ring on $A$. That is, we try to find a universal homomorphism $\gamma : A \to L(A)$, where $L(A)$ is a local ring.

Then a page later

> That is, we are looking for a right adjoint to the forgetful functor $LR\text{-top} \to R\text{-top}$. When such an adjoint exists, it is characterized up to unique local equivalence, and we call it $\text{Spec}(\mathbf{E},A)$, the *spectrum* of $(\mathbf{E},A)$.

Here $R\text{-top}$ is the category of topoi with a distinguished ring, and $LR\text{-top}$ is the category of topoi with a distinguished local ring. You can find more details about the exact morphisms in the paper, but they're what you expect.

Tierney then spends some time describing historical constructions, before finally proposing a new construction, introducing a technique where we build a free *ring* (since this theory is algebraic), then introduce a (grothendieck) topology whose sheaves respect the additional [geometric](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+theory) axioms of a local ring. I mention this mainly because I found it instructive, but it's not particularly relevant.

Now, it's clear that this *is* a good notion of "spectrum", since Tierney proves (on written page 207)

> the $\mathbf{E}$-points of $\text{Spec}(\mathbf{E},A)$... correspond $1$-$1$ to the primes of $A$.

(NB: "primes" in this paper are what we would classically call *complements* of prime ideals. This is to avoid some technical issues with double negation that I don't fully understand)

---

The question, then:

Obviously this idea of "free" local rings *does* lead us to a good notion of spectrum. But it's entirely opaque to me why we would consider it at all. Maybe this is my weakness in algebraic geometry showing? Regardless:

What is the motivation for looking at "free" local rings? And what does this have to do with the construction of the spectrum of a ring? I would prefer answers which give concrete examples if possible.

Thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: I am certainly no expert, but I would say it is just a natural question: Can one find a universal local ring associated to a given ring (a "localification")? The connection to the spectrum is as follows: It turns out that the answer is no (consider $\mathbb{Z}$ for example), but that is because one is looking for local rings in the topos of sets. If one instead heads over to the (big) Zariski topos, one gets a positive answer and the universal local ring associated to some ring $R$ one was searching for turns out to be the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}(R)}$.

Comment: In this sense, the locally ringed space $\text{Spec}(R)$ gives the universal local ring associated $R$, which can be seen as a topos theoretic justification of the Zariski topology.

Comment: @Con -- I agree that it's an interesting and natural question! Your idea about $\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}(R)}$ being the universal local ring associated to $R$ seems like it's what the author had in mind! Do you have a reference for this? Or if not, would you mind writing this up as an answer with some more details? In particular, am I right in thinking that $\mathcal{O}_{\text{Spec}(R)}$ is a local ring in the big Zariski topos over $\text{Spec}(R)$? I guess it should also be "universal" in some sense. Thanks again for your comment, it was already super helpful ^_^

Comment: Yes, for example Theorem 3 (page 449) in the book "Sheaves in geometry and logic" of Mac Lane and Moerdijk. This statement is also known as the computation of the classifying topos of the geometric theory of local rings. The chapter is very comprehensibly written (assuming one knows the necessary tnotions of topos theory) and I can thus only recommend to read it! It indeed is over some scheme. In this case, the scheme would be $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ (so that one gets all affine schemes and hence all rings).

Comment: @Con -- Amazing! Thank you so much ^_^. I'm going to leave this open for a while longer in case more people want to chime in, but if you wrote that up as an answer I would happily accept it in a few days, depending on what else people write

Comment: I believe that this [expository paper of mine](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.13850) is useful to you, in particular Section 3.3. Note that there are two related but different constructions: the free local ring over $R$ is the structure sheaf $\mathbb{A}^1$ of the *big* Zariski topos (the topos of Zariski sheaves on the category of finitely presented $R$-algebras; the free local ring is the tautologous functor $A\mapsto A$), while the free local localization of $R$ is the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec}(R)}$ of the *little* Zariski topos (the topos of sheaves over the spectrum of $R$).